# Fingerprint driver not listed ubuntu lenovo

Tags: lenovo, ubuntu-drivers, fingerprint-reader

I have a lenovo v330 it is not showing the driver in the gui and fprint demo applications. i have tried most tutorials and advice given online. Any other suggestion and help is welcome and appreciated.
thank you

Comment: what flavour of ubuntu do you use,

Comment: Please check whether or not your specific hardware is supported, if not rhen obviously there's no point in installing the software. The fprint PPA web page lists the readers already supported.