# Fingerprint driver for Lenovo V330-14IKB in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, lenovo, 19.04, fingerprint-reader

I can't find the driver of my fingerprint in my Lenovo V330-14IKB, Ubuntu 19.04

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have installed fingerprint gui, fprint-demo, but always have the same answer:

```
:~$ fprintd-enroll
list_devices failed: No devices available
```

(Here is a Link to a similar question: [Fingerprint driver not listed ubuntu lenovo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135965/fingerprint-driver-not-listed-ubuntu-lenovo)
This probably helps giving context

Comment: I'm looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint device is the Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. It is not supported by default ubuntu drivers though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [this project](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues/181) is support it recently, I haven't figured out how to install and make it work for my laptop yet. I update this answer when I know more.